# Git rebase interactive the last n commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have made a bunch of unpushed commits in my feature branch and now want to reorder and partly squash belonging commits visually. I reckon the solution somehow lies in the Git interactive, but how to invoke it?

```
$ git rebase --interactive --onto <the-ID-of-the-first-commit-to-rewrite>
```

just pops up the VI with a

```
noop
```

content followed by commented information. After exiting, my head is reset to the specified commit.

How to correctly trigger the interactive rebase for modifying the commits since a certain commit?

Comment: You're triggering it correctly, you just need to learn how to use it. Read the commented out section, it contains a brief explanation on what you should do.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

you should use

```
git rebase --interactive <sha1>
```

where `<sha1>` should **not** be the sha of the first commit you want to rewrite, but the sha of the commit just before.

if your history looks like this:

```
pick 43576ef last commit
...
pick 5116d42 first commit to rewrite
pick cb85072 last good commit
```

There are two different ways to indicate the commit on which to rebase:

```
git rebase -i cb85072
git rebase -i 5116d42^
```

where

- `^` means the commit just before.
- `-i` is just short for `--interactive`

Comment: It looks like the "onto" caused the problems.

Comment: `but the sha of the commit just before.`, this is the secret to everything

Answer (score 49):

You can also step back from your last commit by some number of commits. For example, if you want to rebase last 5 commits you can use this command:
`git rebase -i HEAD~5`.

Answer (score 46):

To review and rewrite the last `n` commits, use:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

p, pick = use commit

f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message

https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-squash-multiple-commits-into-one-with-git-squash/13231

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is right

#### Though, counting n commits to squash and picking the commit id for rebase is tricky

```
git rebase -i HEAD~[N]   // N is the number of commits, starting from the most recent one
```

[image]

`git rebase -i HEAD~[7]`

**But if u have tons of commit to squash**

```
git rebase -i [commit-id] // [commit-id] is the hash of the commit just before the first one
```

`git rebase -i 6394dc`

---

[Inspired by](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to interactively rebase branch B onto branch A using its last N commits, you can generally do this:

`git rebase -i --onto A B~N B`

e.g.

`git rebase -i --onto master feature~3 feature`

Works well also non-interactively - without `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

I miss the action `rebase` in your instruction:

```
git rebase -i <id-of-commit>
```

Comment: Yes, was a typo. I've fixed the question.